# 1930s version of the novel ‘The Power’?

Tags: story-identification, novel

I recently read [*The Power* by Frank M Robinson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Power_(Robinson_novel)).

It reminded me of a novel that I think was published in the 1930s.

In that novel the superman has powers similar to the one in Robinson’s book but has taken over a city.

He mentally enslaves anyone he comes in contact with and, among other things, is a one-man stud farm. He allows his children who have his power to live and kills the others.

I think even J. Edgar Hoover is hypnotized by him, but a couple of FBI agents who still have free will try to kill him.

Comment: Not the story you are looking for but thank you for the info about 'The Power', that's been bubbling about in my back memory for months now............"hmmmm, that book about the man trying to track down the guy with mental powers, if I could remember a little more plot then I could post it as a query on Stack Exchange!"

Comment: Not exactly the same plot but the year is about right: Odd John by Olaf Stapledon is about a superhumanly intelligent boy who I think also has psychic powers. I may even be forgetting elements of the plot that include things you mention.